# How to Install system app with SE Linux enforced on Galaxy s7 Android 6.0.1

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow

first, sorry for my english :)

i try to install a user app (installed in /data/app/) as system app on my new galaxy s7 : 
- Android 6.0.1
- Rooted
- factory ROM

I follow many tutorials :

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/
http://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/

After reboot, my application is in the the folder /system/app but i can't launch it: it crash when i launch apk directly, even if permission are correctly set.

With another smartphone (samsung s4 rooted with cyanogenmod and SE Permisive), the copy paste technique work well.

Someone knows why i can't launch it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: First tip: for third party apps that are installed as system apps, the **/system/priv-app** path is to be preferred in comparison to **/system/app**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i try it and nothing change. App is in good folder but i can't launch it.

Comment: Heh... couldn't be that simple. Ok, second tip: via a terminal emulator, run `u:object_r:system_file:s0 path_of_your_app.apk` as root and reboot. This changes the context of your app, making SELinux believe it's a genuine system app, so **apply this procedure only if you're absolutely sure that your app is not a malware**.

Comment: No problem. You also gave me the clue I needed to improve my flashable ZIP generator.